# Using the TFS API can I get the project's assembly?

Tags: tfs-sdk, azure-devops

I'm using VS2012 w/ TFS2012.  We have a solution with a bunch of projects in it.  I currently search all items in the branch to find the ".csproj" files.  I was wondering if there's a way that I can get the assembly that's in each project's properties.

What I'd like to do is grab each dll that's created from each of the projects.  I already know which folder the dlls are placed in but there are a bunch of other dlls in there that are not from one of the projects.

Comment: TFS doesn't know anything about projects or assemblies, but the CSPROJ files you've already found are just XML files. That's a Big Hint.

Comment: Ahhhh.  That's a huge hint. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17181785/using-the-tfs-api-can-i-get-the-projects-assembly/17188760#comment24880696_17181785), TFS has no notion of projects or assemblies. It is purely source control.

But having gotten a csproj file, you can use [Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.evaluation.project.aspx) to get the AssemblyName property:

```
var project = new Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project(localProjectFilePath);
var assemblyName = project.GetPropertyValue("AssemblyName");
```